# EF6 Single LINQ Query for nested Lists

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I want to use just single LINQ query to fill nested lists in DB Entities using EntityFramework.

I've got 3 Table Entities.
First class `Cities` contains `List<Houses>` and `Houses` contains `List<Residents>` .

Those classes:

```
class Cities
{
    long CityId {get;set;} 
    string Name {get;set;} 
    List<House> Houses {get;set;} 

}

class Houses 
{
    long CityId {get;set;} 
    string Address {get;set;} 
    List<Resident> Residents {get;set;}

}

class Residents 
{
   long HouseId {get;set;} 
   string FirstName {get;set;} 
   string LastName {get;set;} 
}
```

What I want to achieve is something like that:

```
var cities = ( from city in db.Cities
               select new  // Creating anonymous type to fill List of Houses 
               {
                  CityId = city.CityId,
                  Name   = city.Name, 
                  Houses = db.Houses.Where(h=>h.CityId == city.CityId)
                                    .Select( new // Another anonymous type, but this time this isn't working
                                    {
                                        HouseId = h.HouseId,
                                        Address = h.Address,
                                        Residents = db.Residents.Where(r=>r.HouseId == h.HouseId).ToList()
                                    }).ToList()
                                    .Select( h => new Houses
                                    {
                                        HouseId = h.HouseId,
                                        Address = h.Address,
                                        Residents = h.Houses
                                    }).ToList()
               })
               .ToList()
               .Select( c=> new Cities
               {
                  CityId = c.CityId
                  Name   = c.Name, 
                  Houses = c.Houses
               }).ToList()
```

Unfortunately I am getting error `The entity or complex type Houses cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities`.

It works, just for `Houses = db.Houses.Where(h=>h.CityId ==city.CityId).ToList()`.
But with that I am loosing `Residents` in `Houses`.

Is it even possible to do with one LINQ query?

Comment: Are you trying to write in the DB with a LINQ Query ?

Comment: `Residents = h.Houses` must be a typo. Also, it's highly recommended to use singular class names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to include houses and residents into your cities query:

```
var cities = db.Cities.Include(c => c.Houses.Select(h => h.Residents)).ToList();
```

Comment: This is actually best if it's ok to return the entity types. Not gonna work if the select into anonymous type is done after the `Include` and before the `ToList`. **edit** just realized the entity objects are reconstructed from the anonymous types, so my remark is kinda redundant :)

Comment: @Sergey_Berezovskiy : Thank you. I had some little problems with properly creating Navigation Properties but after that, everything working great!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the navigation properties, not a separate `db` access

```
var Cities = (from city in db.Cities
           select new  // Creating anonymous type to fill List of Houses 
           {
              CityId = city.CityId,
              Name   = city.Name, 
              Houses = city.Houses.Select( new
                                {
                                    HouseId = h.HouseId,
                                    Address = h.Address,
                                    Residents = h.Residents.ToList()
                                }).ToList()
                                .Select( h => new Houses
                                {
                                    HouseId = h.HouseId,
                                    Address = h.Address,
                                    Residents = h.Houses
                                }).ToList()
           })
           .ToList()
           .Select( c=> new Cities
           {
              CityId = c.CityId
              Name   = c.Name, 
              Houses = c.Houses
           }).ToList()
```

Didn't check whole syntax, only replaced `db.Houses.Where(...)` by `city.Houses` (same with `Residents`), so there might be some other issues.